# RewriteRule url to string replace of an &

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to rewrite a url that has an ampersand as the first char in the querystring. I need to be able to remove it.

So the starting url is:

/shop/partner;jsessionid=7giu21yo7tKsqXAL5Wv8.dwapp01?&code=PARTNERDHTE&partnerBackToUrl=partnersiteurl

The &code is my problem

My rules so far are

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^code=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/shop/partner(.*)$ /store/partner/redirect/code/%1? [R=301,L]
```

This works if I remove the & from in front of &code.
I need something that can simply strip out that & from in front of code and then let my rule run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tweak your URL to allow `&` before `code`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)code=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?shop/partner(.*)$ /store/partner/redirect/code/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This helped with my original issue so will mark it as solved but how would i stop any extra parameters being set to the code param. Want to throw out any other params on the query string

Comment: How is that extra parameter being set I couldn't understand

Comment: the code param is getting the rest of the query string starting with the value of code. so it ends up being PARTNERDHTE&partnerBackToUrl=partnersiteurl

Comment: You got it!! Awesome. Much appreciated. I con only upvote it once :)